# Using exists? in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, exists

I am trying to query the DB to see if an Open House exists for a specific listing. If it does, I would like it to display a span. I created a helper based on what I read, but the span is displaying on all of the listings, not just the ones that have an upcoming open house. Any help is appreciated.

ApplicationController:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base    

  def upcoming_oh
    if @open_houses = OpenHouse.exists?
    end
  end
  helper_method :upcoming_oh

end
```

Listings Index:

```
<% upcoming_oh %><span class="label label-nklyn-yellow">Upcoming Open House</span>
```

Comment: oops. didn't mean to delete this. Basically ActiveRecord::exists? when called on the class object will return true if there are ANY rows in the related table, false if there are none.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if your model contains a specific record using exists function

```
if OpenHouse.exists?(your_record)
  # do stuff
end
```

I'm not sure what is OpenHouse, but I think it's a model of your's, anyway this logic should solve your issue

you can use if/else to display/hide a span or div or whatever you want after that like this

```
<% if @condition %>
  <span>
<% end %>
```